# Adding values to different cells depending on conditions - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements, formula, cell

I am not very good with excel formulas, and I would need some help with a process I want to implement:

Simplifying things, I have an excel sheet (sheet n°1) with rows like this:

**Company name | Price | Date**

On other excel sheet (sheet n°2) I have one row for every company, and in each column there are all 12 months. I would need a formula so every time I add a row in the first sheet, the price I add is automatically added to the corresponding company row and in the corresponding month (based on the date) on sheet 2

I am really lost here, I know how to apply simple formulas, but not this, is there a way to add each value to a different cell depending on some conditions?

I forgot to add, that I would need to sum this values in sheet 2, so every time I add a new value, it is summed to the actual value of the corresponding cell.

I hope my english is not to bad, and thank you in advance!! :)

Comment: Would you consider a VBA macro solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMIFS()

```
=SUMIFS($Q:$Q,$P:$P,$A2,$R:$R,">="&EOMONTH(B$1,-1)+1,$R:$R,"<"&EOMONTH(B$1,0)+1)
```

One caveat to this the month headers must be an actual date in the month desired.  This can be formatted any way you want to display.  My cells all contain the 1st of each month as their true dates.

[image]